# Is this Spread Operator Valid Usage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I saw in Angular's [API documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#clone), it declared HttpRequest's clone() method as such:

> clone(update: { headers?: HttpHeaders; reportProgress?: boolean;
> params?: HttpParams; responseType?: "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "text" |
> "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; body?: T; method?: string; url?:
> string; **setHeaders?: { ...; }**; setParams?: { ...; }; }):
> HttpRequest

I wonder is "{...;}" construct after "setHeaders?:" property a valid syntax for type declaration in TypeScript, I searched and did not find the spread operator can be used in the type declaration, is this just appears in Angular's documentation only? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is somewhat confusing. What it's *trying* to get across is that the `setHeaders` property may exist, and if it does, it should be an object with properties, as you can see in [an example here](https://angular.io/guide/http):

```
// Clone the request and set the new header in one step.
const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: authToken } });
```

The code verbatim from the documentation is not valid JavaScript or TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance, this explains the situation from my question and dismissed my doubt with your answer "The code verbatim from the documentation is not valid JavaScript or TypeScript."